# Rotating a border doesn't change window size

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to rotate a `Border` and have the `MainWindow` change his size based on the new space taken by the `Border` rotation.
I've set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` but window size does't take change when I rotated the border.

Do I need to programmatically set the `Width` and `Height` for the MainWindow or this can be achieved changing the xaml code in some other way?

My xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyClass.MainWindow"
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency='True' 
        Topmost='False' Background="Transparent"  ShowInTaskbar='False' 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="Manual">
    <Border Name="MyBorder" 
            BorderBrush="Transparent"
            Background="Transparent"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    </Border>
</Windows>
```

My `c#` code on `Window_KeyDown`:

`# RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform()` is declared at class level.

```
if (e.Key == Key.I)
                {
                    if (rt.Angle + 1 < 360)
                    {
                        rt.Angle += 1;                    
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rt.Angle = 0;                   
                    }    



                MyBorder.RenderTransform = rt;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LayoutTransform` instead of `RenderTransform`

From MSDN: [Transforms Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx)

> - LayoutTransform – A transform that is applied before the layout pass. After the transform is applied, the layout system processes the
>     transformed size and position of the element.
> - RenderTransform – A transform that modifies the appearance of the element but is applied after the layout pass is complete. By using the
>     RenderTransform property instead of the LayoutTransform property, you
>     can obtain performance benefits.

*Example*

```
<Border Name="MyBorder"  
        BorderBrush="Transparent" 
        Background="Transparent" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Border.LayoutTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
    </Border.LayoutTransform>
</Border>
```

So in your case

```
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(0.0, 0.5, 0.5);
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.I)
    {
        if (rt.Angle + 1 < 360)
        {
            rt.Angle += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rt.Angle = 0;
        }
        MyBorder.LayoutTransform = rt;
    }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Why the rotation isn't from the center of the Border?

Comment: In a `LayoutTransform`, a `TranslateTransform` has no effect. The element will be positioned within its parent container. Depending on your situation, `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` and `VerticalAlignment="Center"` might do what you want

Comment: I have read enough on MSDN to understand that I can not do it with LayoutTransform. I'll play with mainwindow position during rotation to simulate the effect!. Thank you again!